# Collision hazard? /var/log populated by repair tool, but actual /var located on separate partition

Tags: boot

Something went wrong in my system, and I used one of the handy boot CDs to repair `grub` and also iron out some mistakes in device assignments. No big deal, and it worked a treat. Good.

However, the repair software on this boot CD loved to write to `/var/log/*` and the "fun" began.

My `/var` is on a **separate** partition, whilst this tool joyfully created a brand new `/var` tree and populated it on my `/` (once it located it with a valid signature).
This is NOT good.

Supposing, I'd just shut down the PC after repairing and (cold-)boot into my own distro again.  This can't really work, can it?
Because I am aware that the system needs a LOT of informational files from `/var` while starting up. (It's not just used as a "log file dump" as most beginners think.) On a VM, I tried that just for the fun of it 2 years ago: the result was that it is impossible to boot with a *virgin* `/var` directory. Not even rebuilding the whole tree (subdirectories only, but no files inside) will work. There seems something really important that the startup routines *do* need for successfully reaching the graphical login screen.

So how can it be avoided if some tool created a `/var/*` tree on your `/` partition and not much later, the UUID of the `/var` partition is read by the system and ...? I had once thought that the `/var` *partition* will **overlay** the "pseudo-/var" on the `/` partition, but that seems not the case.
Plus, this ain't Windows: it's not turned to a `/var.backup` or `/var (2)` or anything of that sort.

**/etc/fstab:** (UUIDs "normalized" for reasons of readability)

```
# /boot on /dev/sda1 after cloning system to new HDD
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee              /boot    ext4  ro        0  1
# /     on /dev/sda2 after cloning system to new HDD
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee              /        ext4  defaults  0  2
# /var (NEW) on /dev/sda6 after cloning system to new HDD
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee              /var     ext4  defaults  0  2
# /home on /dev/sda3 after cloning system to new HDD
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee              /home    ext4  defaults  0  2
# /usr on /dev/sda5 after cloning system to new HDD
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee              /usr     ext4  defaults  0  2
# /opt on /dev/sda7 after cloning system to new HDD
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee              /opt     ext4  defaults  0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you used to have an empty `/var` on your root filesystem, which was used as a mountpoint for the "real /var" which was located on a different filesystem? And when you booted from an ISO, it somehow managed to create a bunch of subdirectories in your "root" `/var` so now you're worried that, after a reboot, the system won't be able to mount your "real /var" because the mountpoint has some files and directories in it?

I don't think you should be concerned, the mount process works just fine in this case. The files located inside your mountpoint become inaccessible (until you unmount the partition), and the whole contents of the mountpoint is "replaced" by the contents of the mounted partition.

The only negative side-effect I can think of is that some disk space will be wasted by the logs you don't need, but, then again, I think it would be quite safe to delete them.

Comment: No. Mount process did NOT work "just fine". The system was looking for the files it needed in `/var` and found zilch, except for the log files the tool had written to the tree which it had previously created. Bootup process hung forever at the message __Stopping log initial device creation__. Went to recovery mode, did a `mount /dev/sdX / -o remount,rw`, removed "false" `/var` directory together with its logs, and everything worked a treat. So it is simply not true that it will "work either way". Somehow I think that it must have to do with the *Populating /var* part ...

Comment: @syntaxerror: why was there "zilch except the log files"? On boot, if your `/etc/fstab` is the same as before, your "real /var" would be mounted on top of any files which may be residing inside the mountpoint. If, for some reason, your "real /var from another partition" did not get mounted - that would be unrelated to the presence of a few files inside the mountpoint, my answer is correct in this part. Did you modify `/etc/fstab`? Did you unplug the hard drive which hosts your "real /var"? Is that other partition corrupt?

Comment: @syntaxerror: It's not a matter of opinion :) I suggest you to read `man mount`, which describes the behaviour I'm talking about in the second paragraph from the top: "The previous contents (if any) and owner and mode of dir  become  invisible,  and  as  long  as  this
       filesystem remains mounted, the pathname dir refers to the root of the filesystem on device.
"

Comment: also, the mount point (/var on the root filesystem) must exist for the mount to work, so I'm not sure how deleting the mountpoint fixed things. Can you show the contents of your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Sure, integrated them into my OP. Nothing fancy in there though: `/` gets mounted first, then `/var`. I guess that's a sensible order. Because otherwise the false "/var" in root (mounted *later* in the other scenario) would probably mingle somehow into the one that is already there. Perhaps I should emphasize again that the thought of moving `/var` to its own "realm" didn't come up UNTIL I moved my whole system to a new HDD (besides, what a wise thought, as it turned out that my previous one was on the verge of getting seriously ill!!)